# Is $ \left\lfloor \frac{n+3}{2} \right\rfloor = \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor +1$?

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

$$ \left\lfloor \frac{n+3}{2} \right\rfloor = \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor +1$$ 
Is it correct?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you plugged in an odd number and even number to check it?

Comment: Consider $n = 1$.

Comment: Consider $n=3$, $n=5$

Comment: A useful fact is that whenever $n$ is an integer, $\lfloor x+n\rfloor=\lfloor x\rfloor+n$. (Try to prove it; it’s not hard.) Here that means that $$\left\lfloor\frac{n+3}2\right\rfloor = \left\lfloor\frac{n+1}2+1\right\rfloor = \left\lfloor\frac{n+1}2\right\rfloor+1\;,$$ and you can easily check that this is not the same as $\left\lfloor\frac{n}2\right\rfloor+1$. (Of course as Andrew Salmon pointed out, you can also check very directly that your proposed equality doesn’t hold in general.

Comment: It would involve $\Bigl\lfloor\dfrac{n+1}2\Bigr\rfloor=\Bigl\lfloor\dfrac n2\Bigr\rfloor$. Is that always true?

Comment: Consider any negative $n$...

Answer (score 3):

$$ \left\lfloor \frac{n+3}{2} \right\rfloor = \left\lfloor \frac{n+1}{2} +1 \right\rfloor = \left\lfloor \frac{n+1}{2} \right\rfloor +1 $$

so your proposition is true iff
$$\left\lfloor \frac{n+1}{2} \right\rfloor = \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor $$

Answer (score 2):

The correct formula is:

$$\left\lfloor \frac{n+3}{2} \right\rfloor=\left\lfloor \frac{n+1}{2} +1  \right\rfloor=\left\lfloor \frac{n+1}{2} \right\rfloor  +1 $$